# Convert XUL application to web app

Tags: xul

Is it possible to convert an existing XUL application to a pure web application without a complete rewrite?  Are there any existing guides on doing this?

There is an existing project based on XUL / Mozilla Application Framework that I would like to see as a web application.  But it seems that with FF4 this would no longer be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XUL Runner if you like to keep it like a desktop app or use the Ample SDK which supports XUL in HTML pages and it does a rendering using HTML and JavaScript.